# What a local android.app.Service needed for?

Tags: android

I can't figure it out from the docs. A remote service makes sence, but not local. When should I use a Service instead of a POJO?

> A facility for the application to tell the system about something it wants to be doing in the background

What will happen, if I don't tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service is something that runs all the time even if your app was closed. You can also config your service to start automatically after device was rebooted. Look at the service as at the separate process, "separate app" which can run in background. If you need do some heavy or regular work on background you should create Service. You can say that also Thread works in background, but the big difference that Thread will die, when your app will be closed and service can be configured to run all the time.

Few example of service usage.

1. Messaging. For example you want your user will be able to get some message from you remote server in any time. If your app will be closed you will not have any connection with remote server. (your app can be also closed by Android, when there in no enough memory). In this situation you can create the Service which will wait for messages from server in background and notify user when message arrived.
2. Checking for updates. For example you wants to check for updates in background, and notify the user when there are updates. If you don this without service your app can be closed or device can be rebooted, but if you use properly configured service it will run on background all the time.
3. Show user location. Get user location can take few minutes, for example you want to get the user location immediately when user opens the app. You create service which can get user location even when app closes, than when user opens the app you just get last user location from your service.

Comment: What do you mean by "closing the app"? Not the process termination I guess, because when it dies, the service dies too

Comment: You can configure your service to restart automatically after process termination too. But when I say "closing the app" I mean closed by user with finger swipe.

Comment: What will happen, if OS decides to reclaim memory and kill background apps? Will Service prevent killing the process? The doc doesn't say about that.

Comment: It will be killed too, but than it will automatically restarted (if you configured it). You can also set it startForeground. "You can set this flag if killing your service would be disruptive to the user, such as if your service is performing background music playback, so the user would notice if their music stopped playing." Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)

Comment: Thanks. Conclusion: local Services are useless, unless you use `startForeground()`

Comment: You are welcome, but you made wrong conclusion or maybe I explained it in bad way. Almost every big app use local services. You can go to Settings->Apps->Running and look at the count of local services in popular apps by yourself on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I would only use an IntentService to do work of the main thread.

And nothing will happen if you don't tell :)